# SQL Finding count of purchases per day, per type of order?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

so I have a SQL Database in Google BigQuery that has the purchases Order timestamp in UTC Format, which I use the DAYOFWEEK Function to convert into a number (then I use the CASE Statement to convert to a human readable name)

The SQL Query is:

```
SELECT TypeOfDrink,
        CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=1) THEN 'Sunday' END AS Sunday,
        CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=2) THEN 'Monday' END AS Monday,
        CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=3) THEN 'Tuesday' END AS Tuesday,
        CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=4) THEN 'Wednesday' END AS Wednesday,
        CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=5) THEN 'Thursday' END AS Thursday,
        CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=6) THEN 'Friday' END AS Friday,
        CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=7) THEN 'Saturday' ELSE 'UnDefined' END AS Saturday,
        COUNT(TypeOfDrink) AS AmountBought 
        FROM CafeX_bigdata.Order 
        GROUP BY Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday, TypeOfDrink
```

However, I'm getting this as the output:

```
Row TypeOfDrink Sunday  Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday   Saturday   AmountBought     
1   Single Origin Caffè Latte   null    null    Tuesday null    null    null    UnDefined   12   
2   Cappuccino  null    null    Tuesday null    null    null    UnDefined   130  
3   Caffè Mocha null    null    Tuesday null    null    null    UnDefined   161  
4   Macchiato   null    null    Tuesday null    null    null    UnDefined   174  
5   Caffè Latte null    null    Tuesday null    null    null    UnDefined   233
```

In this case, it goes through all the days, and lists the Amount bought.. however I Just want it all in one line, where they would list the values for everyday of the week in one Row, versus 7 rows with NULLS!

I'm using BigQuery, so some of the SQL is a little different. How would I do this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation.  It looks like this:

```
SELECT TypeOfDrink,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sunday,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Monday,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Tuesday,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Wednesday,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Thursday,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Friday,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt)=7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Saturday,
       COUNT(TypeOfDrink) AS AmountBought 
FROM CafeX_bigdata.Order 
GROUP BY TypeOfDrink;
```

Comment: To make Gordon's code even more readable  - try `SUM(DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt) = W)` instead of `SUM(CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(CreateAt) = W) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. Result should be same but code is less verbose

Comment: Question.. how do I go about switching the rows and columns? I want to put the Drinks as Coloums, and the days of the weeks as the rows?

Comment: @retrojacket . . . That would be a different question, but the idea is the same.  The conditions in the `case` would be for each drink and the `group by` would be by `dateofweek()`.

Comment: i recommend you to submit separate question as it is really different one

Comment: There is a big difference here - number of weekdays is constant, small and most important well known in advance. Which is not a case with number of drinks. So, conceptually all the same, but implementation wise is going to be more involved